# How to get rid of Check in- Check out in SharePoint completely?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

One of the issues I am seeing with Office 365/SharePoint online is I can't get rid of Check In- Check out even after doing the below config in versioning settings at the library level.FYI, I do have SharePoint server publishing features enabled at the site collection level.

[image]

I have some mandatory metadata columns which is necessary from an architecture perspective. Also they are not set to a default value because that is not something client is willing to see.

Now the issue is the user is still able to check out/in the document from the ribbon in the top or by clicking on the three dots next to the document name. I want to remove that or stop user from doing that.

[image]

[image]

Is there an OOTB way to achieve this potentially or may be a programmatic approach to get rid of it may be using JSOM since I am working with Office 365/SharePoint online. Please help if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's *not* the best solution, but you can just hide this button with CSS:

```
[id$='Ribbon.Documents.EditCheckout'],
[title='Check Out']{
  display:none;
}
```

Easiest way would be to add this CSS file to the site like so:

[image]

It won't work with the **Modern pages** unless you create an SPFx extension app.

Comment: It might work to hide the buttons but be aware if the document gets in the library through drag and drop, it won’t ask for the required fields and they will not be filled in, and will go in as checked out.